# Angular: Reloading url with child route reloads parent component instead of child with correct url

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I feel like this is something simple and that I don't have something correct with my routing. I have built a simple example.

My issue: When I reload the page on a child route, it is reloading the parent component, not the child component. Navigation is correct. I have the correct router-outlets in each of the components and if I click though my hierarchy I can navigate fine and the url is correct. However, if I reload the page with the child url I am on, I get the parent component loaded and not the child component with it. The reloaded url is the correct child url.

What I am missing? Below is my routes as defined in the module. I just can't seem to find why it wouldn't reload the correct component if the url and params are correct. Thanks!

**Updated with a App Routing module to be more consistent with standards

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PointListComponent } from './Components/Nav-Components/point-list/point-list.component';
import { CoreDataComponent } from './Components/Nav-Components/Core Data/core-data/core-data.component';
import { ZoneSnapshotComponent } from './Components/Type-Components/Zone/zone-snapshot/zone-snapshot.component';
import { ZoneWrapperComponent } from './Components/Type-Components/Zone/zone-wrapper/zone-wrapper.component';
import { ZoneTransactionsComponent } from './Components/Type-Components/Zone/zone-transactions/zone-transactions.component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: 'pointlist', component: PointListComponent, 
    children: [
      { path: 'coredata/:prodPointId', component: CoreDataComponent ,
        children: [       
              { path: 'zonesnapshot', component: ZoneSnapshotComponent}, 
              { path: 'zonedetail', component: ZoneWrapperComponent}, 
              { path: 'zonetrans', component: ZoneTransactionsComponent}, 
              { path: '', redirectTo: 'zonesnapshot', pathMatch: 'full'}       
            ] 
           }       
        ]
      },     
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Try moving your redirect route to the bottom of the children array

Comment: Moving the redirect to the end had no affect. Maybe I did not explain correctly. If a reload the page on the child route for zonesnapshot, it is loading pointlist  not zonesnapshot, but keeping the child url for zonesnapshot.

Comment: The next thing I would try, if you can't get it working in StackBlitz, would be to hook to the router events and log out what URLs are coming through.

Comment: might be hard to get it in StackBlitz. I do have trace on in the routes. This is the last part of it in navigation end: NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/pointlist/coredata/3/zonesnapshot', urlAfterRedirects: '/pointlist/coredata/3/zonesnapshot'). To me looks correct. Just baffled it doesn't load the correct component.

Comment: Yeah, is this the only routing in your app? Can you post the routing module?

Comment: its all in the app module at the moment, but I plan on creating a separate routing once I can get this resolve. I have updated the code above to all items involved with the routing and the current components in use. This is the only routing I have currently.

Comment: Off the wall idea but have you thought about making it a lazy loaded module and bringing it in that way? Sorry, working off my phone at the moment and don't have access to try to reproduce your issue currently.

Comment: I have not tried lazy loading, but I don't have a separate module yet. This is all in app module so there isn't another module to lazy load.

Comment: Right, I was just throwing that out there as a suggestion. I'm baffled as well whytit doesn't work. Everytime I've set routing like this up it's been lazy loaded and worked is what spawned that suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, it is driving me a little nuts to be honest haha. I've been all over the angular routing site and to the best of my knowledge reloading this page should work. All the navigation is fine, but if someone chooses to reload the page, I want them to stay on the child component they should be on.

Comment: it looks like it has something to do with my router-outlets. I took the coredata out so it wasn't a child of pointlist and the page started reloading. You should be able to nest multiple levels of child routes correct? That was only two levels, but started working when it was only one level.

Comment: Wow, it was a css issue with one of my components. Always something isn't it. Thanks for trying to help. It was appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I wasn't more help I'd have never even thought to look at the css.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was related to a css issue that was not allowing the router-outlet in the child component to be shown correctly.

Comment: You must attach a more detailed solution for others, not just solve it for yourself and be happy about. Someone will come here to find a solution and will only see that it was css-issue and nothing more about it.